# format regexp constant on several lines for readability

Tags: awk

For learning purposes I am implementing a little regexp matcher for telephone numbers. My goal is **readability**, not the shortest possible gawk program:

```
# should match
#1234567890
#123-456-7890
#123.456.7890
#(123)456-7890
#(123) 456-7890 

BEGIN{
    regexp="[0-9]{10},[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4},\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
    len=split(regexp,regs,/,/)
}
{for (i=1;i<=len;i++)
    if ($0 ~ regs[i]) print $0
}
```

For better readability I would like to split the line `regexp="...` on several lines like:

```
regexp="[0-9]{10}
       ,[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4}
       ,\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

Is there an easy way to do this in awk?

Comment: I would think that starting with the regs[] array and putting each pattern into its own cell would be more self-documenting, i.e. `regs[1]="[0-9]{10}"` ..... I'm not certain about what the difference between something like `($0 ~ /regex/) AND ($0 ~ regs[i])` will work out. Also, how would you propose to manage changes to your regex as it gets bigger and bigger, (hard to see where changes are, might be on the far right, AND more importantly, if you require comma char ',', then you have to change your separator ! ;-)! Good luck.

Comment: your regex is not correct. 123.456-789 or 123-456.789 will be matched. but they are not in your list. you may need group.

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for you watchful eye. Can i use grouping with the "$0 ~ regs[i]"-form or do i need to use gensub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concensus seems to be that there is no simple way to split multiline strings without disturbing awk? Thanks for the other ideas, but make me as the programmer do the work of the computer what i don't enjoy. So i came up with this solution, which in my opinion is pretty close to a kind of executable specification. I use the base and here documents and process redicrection to create the files for awk on the fly:

```
#!/bin/bash

# numbers that should be matched
read -r -d '' VALID <<'valid'
1234567890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
(123)456-7890
(123) 456-7890 
valid
# regexp patterns that should match
read -r -d '' PATTERNS <<'patterns'
[0-9]{10}
[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4}
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
\([0-9]{3}\) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}
patterns

gawk --re-interval 'NR==FNR{reg[FNR]=$0;next}
  {for (i in reg) 
    if ($0 ~ reg[i]) print $0}' <(echo "$PATTERNS") <(echo "$VALID")
```

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN {
    regs[1] = "[0-9]{10}"
    regs[2] = "[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4}"
    regs[3] = "\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
    c = 3
    }
{
  for (i = 1; i <= c; i++)
    if ($0 ~ regs[i]) 
      print $0
  }
```

If your awk implementation supports length(array) - use it (see Jaypal Singh comments below):

```
BEGIN {
    regs[1] = "[0-9]{10}"
    regs[2] = "[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4}"
    regs[3] = "\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
    }
{
  for (i = 1; i <= length(regs); i++)
    if ($0 ~ regs[i]) 
      print $0
  }
```

Consider also the side effects of the computed (dynamic) regular expressions,
see the [GNU awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps) for more information.

Comment: +1 … Though I would change `i <= 3` to `i <= length(regs)` as it will offer extensibility if the `regs` array has been later added with more `regexes`.

Comment: Hi @JaypalSingh, good point! It's worth noting that length(array) is an extension (i.e. it's not available in all modern awk implementations).

Answer (score 3):

The following link may contain the answer you were looking for :

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Statements_002fLines.html

It says that in awk script files or on the command line of certain shells, awk commands can be split over several lines in the same manner as makefile commands. Simply end the line with a backslash (`\`) and awk will discard the newline character upon parsing. Combine this with implicit concatenation of strings (similar to C) and the solution could be

```
BEGIN {
    regexp = "[0-9]{10}," \
             "[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4}," \
             "\\([0-9]{3}\\)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
    len = split(regexp, regs, /,/)
}
```

Nevertheless, I would favor the solution that stores the regular expressions in an array directly: it better reflects the intent of the statement and doesn't force the programmer to do any more work than required. Also, there is no need for the `length` function since one can use the foreach syntax. One should note that arrays in awk are like maps in Java or dictionaries in Python in that they don't associate a range of integer indices with values. Rather they map string keys to values. Even if integers are used as keys, they are implicitly converted to a string. Thus the `length` function is not always provided since it is misleading.

```
BEGIN {
    regs[1] = "[0-9]{10}"
    regs[2] = "[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4}"
    regs[3] = "\\([0-9]{3}\\)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
}

{
    for (i in regs) {        # i recieves each key added to the regs array
        if ($0 ~ regs[i]) {
            print            # by default `print' prints the whole record
            break            # we can stop finding a regexp
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `break` command exits the `for` loop prematurely. This is necessary if each record must only be printed once, even though several regular expressions could match.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can store the regexp in variables, then join them, e.g.:

```
awk '{
       COUNTRYCODE="WHATEVER_YOUR_CONTRY_CODE_REGEXP"
       CITY="CITY_REGEXP"
       PHONENR="PHONENR_REGEX"
       THE_WHOLE_THING=COUNTRYCODE CITY PHONENR
       if ($0 ~ THE_WHOLE_THING) { print "BINGO" }
     }'
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I want to introduce my favorite to this question as it hasn't been mentioned yet. I like to use the simple string append operation of awk, that is just the default operator between two terms, as multiplication in typical math notations:

```
x = x"more stuff"
```

appends `"more stuff"` to `x` and sets the new value to `x` again. So you can write

```
regexp = ""
regexp = regexp"[0-9]{10}"
regexp = regexp"[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4}"
regexp = regexp"\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

To control additional split characters like newlines between the snippets most languages I know of and awk too, can use the array join and split methods to make a string from an array and convert back the string into an array, without loosing the original structure of the array (for example the newline markers):

```
i = 0
regexp[i++] = "[0-9]{10}"
regexp[i++] = "[0-9]{3}[-.][0-9]{3}[.-][0-9]{4}"
regexp[i++] = "\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

Using `regstr = join(regexp, ",")` add the split "," you used. 
Of course there is no join function in awk, but I guess it is very simple
to implement, knowing the string append operation above.

My method seem to look more verbose but has the advantage, that the original data, the regexp string snippets in this part, are prepended by a string constant for each snippet. That means the code can be generated by a very simple algorithm (or even some editors shortcuts).